# form that records time between key presses

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, timer, timing

Hello I'm new to c# and I want to make a form that runs in the background and records the time between the press of the letter X.
For example:
x 0
x 1.124
x 1.025
x 2.345
x 2.345
x 0.769
x 0.769
the purpose of this would be to see if someone is using a macro.(time between presses would be the same).

I want some ideas.
Thank you.

Comment: There are macros which can simulate human (by randomizing delay). There are humans who press keys like macros.

Comment: Google "winforms low level keyboard hook", lots of hits.

Answer (score 1):

create a stopwatch and start stop the stopwatch on the keydown event

Thats the basic idea, but you mean a program that records keystrokes for the entire computer, or just within 1 form of an application?

Comment: for the entire computer.people would start a game on a website with this form working in the background.at the end they could just stop it and save the results.